# Will the google admin directory api support the new extended user attributes released in July 2014?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

According to the google apps blog post, http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2014/07/richer-profile-information-with.html, there will be support for extended user attributes to capture secondary email address, Employee ID, Employee Type, Title, Manager, Department and Cost Center. Will these fields also be exposed through the Directory API? And if so, when?

Answer (score 0):

The fields are already supported by the Admin SDK Directory API (and have been since day 1 of it's release). See the [full table of user attributes](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users).

Comment: Are you referring to the organizations array? When trying to use that with the php api client it just ignores whatever you set there and never returns anything for that attribute. We use the APIs to create/edit/suspend users and manage aliases, but for whatever reason it doesnt seem to support me setting anything for organizations and it never returns anything for that attribute for users either. Perhaps it is a client bug instead?

Comment: There are lists for organizations, addresses, relations, phones, etc. Can you confirm you've updated to the latest version of the Google PHP library? https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client